# is there anyway to find out which apps were launched on my android device?

Tags: android

Sometimes I really need to know if anybody has used my phone while I wasn't home? Is there any app to reveal such a thing? something like "launched apps history".

Comment: You will have to create a service and monitor the process ids using package manager class so you can get the list of processes started on your device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a built in provision for achieving this, but there are a number of available applications that allow you to monitor this, such as KidLogger. KidLogger is somewhat outdated, but I think there are other apps available too.

The other option is to download a log viewing program (or export the logs to your computer) like CatLog so that you can view the system logs. Application calls should be visible in the logs. I do believe that this requires root access though.